# Atomic operations on floats

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, atomic

Most languages provide functions for atomic `int` operations (add, compare & swap, etc.).

Why not for float types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's ponder floating point atomics, from the OS/hardware design point of view...

Atomics exist because they're needed for synchronisation. What does the majority of synchronisation involve? Handles, flags, mutexes, spinlocks - things whose actual value is meaningless as long as it's consistent per user and different between users. Even for something like a semaphore where the value is more meaningful - it's still about *counting* rather than *measuring*, so 32 bits is worth 32 bits whatever we deem it to represent.

Secondly, technical issues. Pretty much anything we can program on does integer operations. Not so floating point - when FP operations are being emulated by the C library, those atomics are going to be between difficult and impossible to implement. Even in hardware, FP operations are usually going to be slower than integer, and who wants slow locks? The design of the FPU itself may even make it difficult to implement atomic operations - e.g. if it's hanging off a coprocessor interface without any direct access to the memory bus.

Second-and-a-halfth, if we want `float`, surely we want `double` as well? But `double` often has the problem of being bigger than a machine word, ruling out atomicity of even loads and stores on many architectures.

Third, when it comes to things like atomics, CPU architects tend to implement what system designers and OS folks are demanding, and OS folks don't exactly love floating point in general - stupid extra registers to save, slowing down context switches... More instructions/features in the hardware cost power and complexity, and if the customers don't want them...

So, in short, there's not enough of a use case, so there's no hardware support, so there's no language support. Of course, on some architectures you can [roll your own atomics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional), and I imagine GPU compute may have more demand for synchronisation on primarily floating-point hardware, so who knows if it'll stay that way?

Answer (score 2):

To improve upon previous answers in the context of Go, we can use https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64bits and https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Float64frombits to convert float64s to and from uint64s without the direct use of the unsafe package.

Given a uint64, we can then use all the available atomic primitives.

```
type AtomicFloat64 uint64

func (f *AtomicFloat64) Value() float64 {
    return math.Float64frombits(atomic.LoadUint64((*uint64)(f)))
}

func (f *AtomicFloat64) Add(n float64) float64 {
    for {
        a := atomic.LoadUint64((*uint64)(f))
        b := math.Float64bits(math.Float64frombits(a) + n)
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint64((*uint64)(f), a, b) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can try
```
var x AtomicFloat64
x.Add(1)
x.Add(1)
x.Add(1)
x.Value() -> -0.25 certainly not 3
```
If you want better way check out this code:
https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/prometheus/value.go#L91

Comment: You're absolutely right! This code has a bug. Thanks for noticing, I'll update the answer.

Comment: There is no need to do `a := atomic.LoadUint64` because it could change before the next `if` statement. See https://golang.org/src/sync/atomic/64bit_arm.go?s=508:615#L27

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the original question was tagged with Go and was slightly different, so here's what I was about to answer anyway, sorry if it's not the full answer for the edited question :)

With Go you can swap any pointer value atomically with a little trip on the unsafe dark side:

http://play.golang.org/p/aFbzUMhfEB

Excerpt:

```
var uptr unsafe.Pointer
var f1, f2 float64

f1 = 12.34
f2 = 56.78
// Original values
fmt.Println(f1, f2)
uptr = unsafe.Pointer(&f1)
atomic.SwapPointer(&uptr, unsafe.Pointer(&f2))
f1 = *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(uptr))
// f1 now holds the value of f2, f2 is untouched
fmt.Println(f1, f2)
```

The swap call (and other atomic operations like [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)) maps to a CPU architecture's instruction that guarantees this atomicity (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1762179/1094941 for more details). As for why there is no assembly support for floats, I don't know.

Comment: OpenCL offers atomic single precision floating point operations.  It supports a slightly smaller subset of C. http://www.khronos.org/  It is meant to be portable, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

CAS (compare-and-swap) is the most important atomic operation, since others (`add`, `and`, `or`, etc.) can be simulated in terms of it.

I think an important reason why floating point numbers don't have CAS functionality is because equality does not work with IEEE754 floats in the same way it does with integral types. For example you will  not know if swap was successful with CAS whenever an old expected or an actual value turned out to be a `NaN`. Remember that comparing a `NaN` to any other value including `NaN` will always return false.

With regards to atomic bitwise and arithmetic operations they are simply a lot less useful for floating point than they are for integers.